# How would you express "pausing to think" in Japanese?

Tags: words, nuances, colloquial-language

I was wondering how would you express pausing to think in Japanese. So for example in English it would be said as "hmmmm...".

I believe あのう。。。 can be used but are there any more ways to do so?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- あー
- うーむ
- うーん
- うーんと
- えー
- えーっと
- えーと
- そのう
- ふうむ
- んー

I am sure there are more.

Comment: Let's not forget the corner case of teeth sucking.  Thinking + disdain/contempt.  :D

Answer (score 1):

A few more:

- そうですねぇ〜
- そっかぁ〜
- まー

Note that the first two do not necessarily imply the listener's agreement with what the speaker actually said.

Comment: That's some great additions. Thank you! I think I saw an article for these kind of expressions used in Japanese. I'm gonna try and sniff it out.